# Most closely related words to a certain word

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, statistics, correlation

Given a word I want to find the closely related words (e.g., finding correlations). Can you please suggest accurate tools to start with

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/word2vec

Answer (score 1):

Please refine your question.

Using a pre-trained word2vec model e.g gensim, you can compute the cosine similarity between the vector representations of words.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you please provide some more details in this regard. I read many articles and I am still unable to understand the as I am very new to this area.